# Why is my count returning a syntax error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [db_owner].[get_checkin_likes]
@likes integer
AS
Select count(*) 
from
(
  select checkin_id as Checkin, users_id as 'Liked by'
  from checkin_likes
  where @likes = checkin_id
)
```

When I execute this command I expect two things:

1. I expect to get a list of all the users that like the particular checkin I selected
2. I expect to get a count of how many users like the particular checkin

However, when I try to run the command it returns this:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure get_checkin_likes, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Any suggetions as to how to fix this or why it's happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to name your subquery; try putting something after the final parenthesis:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [db_owner].[get_checkin_likes]
@likes integer
AS
Select count(*) 
from
(
  select checkin_id as Checkin, users_id as 'Liked by'
  from checkin_likes
  where @likes = checkin_id
) a
```

I probably should mention that when you run this query you will only get the count back. I'm not sure of your use-case here, but you can do an OVER and return everything with a count at the end

EDIT:

I would personally do this and have it all in the one record set:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [db_owner].[get_checkin_likes]
@likes integer
AS

  select checkin_id as Checkin
    , users_id as 'Liked by'
    , COUNT(checkin_id) OVER () AS total_rows, 
  from checkin_likes
  where @likes = checkin_id
```

Comment: Ok it's returning the count, however it's not returning which users liked which checkin. How can I write the store procedure in such a way that when I execute it, it will give me both a list of all the users that liked the checkin and a count of how many users liked it? Thank you for you help I'm still very new to SQL.

Comment: @SirAskALot Sorry, fire drill at work: Edit to reflect what I would do to get your results

Comment: +1. Nice to see someone using window functions. As an aside, its better to use "AS a" rather than just "a" for the table alias.